# MS Dynamics AX 2009 SSRS reports

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services, ax

I have to create AX 2009 ssrs reports.

In my machine I only have Visual Studio 2008. All data and tables are in AX 2009.

Do i have to install AX 2009 on my machine or there is a way to fetch records from AX 2009 from MS ssrs tool?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to install AX 2009 Client on your machine, because add-on (Reporting Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio) for creating reports is installed through AX client setup.

Answer (score 1):

You could either install AX client and reporting tools on your local machine, or you could install Visual Studio 2008 on a machine that already has an ax client and reporting tools installed. Where I work we use Terminal Services to connect to a server that has all of these tools installed so that we can develop on the server rather than on our local machines.